# Linting HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to watch HTML/CSS files and run a linter when they are saved.  I'm not using a specific build systems, rather, just calling node cli's directly from my package.json file.

I'm using ESLint to take care of javascript - can anyone recommend a similar linter for HTML/CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`stylelint`](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint) for stylesheets and [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) for html